# Replace empty cells with NULL values in large number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, null

I have SQL table that has a large number of columns. For some reason, some columns have empty cells instead of NULL cells. I would like to make all empty cells in all the columns to be NULL.

I know that the way to go for a single column is:

```
 UPDATE your_table SET column = NULL WHERE column = ''
```

However, I am not sure how to execute a similar logic efficiently for all columns without having to write the column names one by one.

Thanks,

Comment: @DanBracuk what fun is that? Learning to do this efficiently now could save untold minutes down the road.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Run the following query:

```
SELECT 'UPDATE yourtable SET ' + name + ' = NULL WHERE ' + name + ' = '''';'
FROM syscolumns
WHERE id = object_id('yourtable')
  AND isnullable = 1;
```

The output of this query will be a chunk of SQL script like this:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET column1 = NULL WHERE column1 = '';
UPDATE yourtable SET column2 = NULL WHERE column2 = '';
UPDATE yourtable SET column3 = NULL WHERE column3 = '';
-- etc...
```

Copy and paste that SQL script into a new query and run it to update all your columns.

Comment: That's a neat trick! Thanks! But is there any way I can pass the results of your first query to something that I can run automatically? I am doing this via C#, that's why... Thanks!

Comment: Depends how you're doing your db access, but say you're using C# and Linq To SQL, you could do something like this: 
`using (MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext())
{
    string queryBuilder = "...first query from above...";
    var resultsetOfUpdateQueries = db.ExecuteQuery<string>(queryBuilder);
    foreach (string oneUpdateQuery in resultsetOfUpdateQueries)
    {
        db.ExecuteCommand(oneUpdateQuery);
    }
}`

No worries about SQL injection because the only variable components of the dynamic SQL statement will all be column names from a dictionary table.

Comment: Why would you do this, presumably one off task, in c#?

Comment: The reason I need to do this is that I have used `bulk insert` from a `csv` file to populate my SQL table. For some odd reason, some of the empty cells in the `csv` file got translated as `NULL` in the table, while others got translated as empty cells in table. The transformation above is to make all the empty tables unified.

Comment: @mayou To execute this in one fell swoop using Robert's code above, see the stored procedure code I posted below (too long to post in this comment). Kudos to Robert N as this has saved me tons of time over the last couple months.

Answer (score 3):

You could do a query on `syscolumns` to get a list of columns, and use the results to construct your query.

```
select quotename(name) + ' = nullif (' + quotename(name)+ ','''')'
from syscolumns 
where id = object_id('yourtable')
```

Additionally, if you write your query as

```
update yourtable
set
    yourcolumn=nullif(yourcolumn, ''),
    yourcolumn2=nullif(yourcolumn2, ''),
    ...
```

then you can do it in a single query without a where clause

Comment: I would still have to write each column to check for the `nullif`. That wouldn't be very efficient.

Comment: Thanks. I get the first part, but I am not sure how to use the result of the first query to write the second one: i.e. how to pass the column names obtained from the first query to the second query

Comment: @Mariam The easy way is to copy the results and paste them into a new query.

Comment: An example of how to copy/paste?  Come on now.

Comment: @Goat Co I meant an example of an `automatic` passing of the results of the query to the second query. It is quite obvious I wasn't asking for a trivial copy/paste.

Answer (score 3):

I actually use Robert N's answer above daily when I'm importing flat file data sets, so I put it into a stored procedure that I could pass a table name to. It just populates a temp table with the update statements, then executes each row in the table.

```
    USE [master]
    GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    -- =============================================
    -- Author:      LikeableBias
    -- Create date: 2016-06-27
    -- Description: Finds and NULLs all blank values in table where column allows nulls
    -- =============================================
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_NullBlanks] 
        @tablename NVARCHAR(MAX)
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --------Insert update statements to temp table for execution
    DECLARE @statements TABLE (statement NVARCHAR(MAX))
    INSERT INTO @statements
            ( statement )
        SELECT ('UPDATE '+@tablename+' SET [' + name + '] = NULL WHERE ' + name + ' = '''';')
        FROM syscolumns
        WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(@tablename)
        AND isnullable = 1;
    --------Open cursor, execute statements, then close cursor
    DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FOR
        SELECT statement FROM @statements
    OPEN cur
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @statement
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
        EXEC sys.sp_executesql @statement
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @statement
    END
    CLOSE cur
    DEALLOCATE cur

    END
    GO
```