# Replacing Null to Blank in multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, null

I have multiple null values in a table including different rows and columns, how I can replace them with one query like using 'all" or *, wherever the Null values in the whole table?

Comment: show us your query,which you have tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update columns with Null values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923721/update-columns-with-null-values)

Comment: Your answer would be here. please check
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056502/replace-empty-cells-with-null-values-in-large-number-of-columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace empty cells with NULL values in large number of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056502/replace-empty-cells-with-null-values-in-large-number-of-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Check if column value is null,if yes update with blank values like below code

```
Update TableName
SET TableName.Column=''
WHERE TableName.Column IS NULL
```

For Multiple Columns

```
UPDATE TableName
SET col1 = COALESCE(col1,''),
   col2 = COALESCE(col2,''),
   col3 = ...
   Coln = COALESCE(coln,'')
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried what you suggested, but it showing error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'column'.

My table name is GRN_M
so i wrote query as 
update grn_m
set grn_m.Column=' '
where grn_m.Column IS Null

Comment: @RahatAli Actually grn_m.Column is your column name for which you want to replace Null values with Blank.Please specify the column names there.

Comment: I understood, as there are so many columns with Null value, I just want to do them in one go, do not want to SET giving every column name, also mentioning name after Where. So is there any way to do it in one go, such as All or * ?

Comment: @RahatAli i have updated the above code for multiple column updation.please try with that